# Fetch only some rows from URL in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, url

I developed iOS  app,

Which fetches data from `url` and displays in `tableview`, my `url` contains lots of data around 2000 rows of tableview.. this takes a lot of time to display..

But i want to implement something like, application should fetch only first 25 rows from `url`, display it and then fetch again next 25 rows from url and display it and so on..

is it possible to implement this in iOS ? if yes, then will you please share some ideas ?

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: does it take a long time to download, or a long time to display?

Comment: You should only be displaying the cells that are visible. Are you really trying to create 2000 table cells?

Comment: yes in, datasource method of UITableview called `numberOfRowsInSection` i am returning [myarray count]; and my array contains 2000 rows..

Comment: how to display only some rows that are visible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible in iOS. There are two ways in which you can do this.

1. Change Your `URL` response : Here what you can do is. Make sure your URL only returns 25 data at a time. And, append this data to your array and display it.
2. What you can do is. Fetch all the rows from URL. And change : `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

this delegate method. Each time you want to show next 25 rows.

This is how you can do it. When first time your delegate method is called :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rowCount;
}
```

When next time UITableView gets reloaded. What you can do is send 25 + 25 rows. And so on. May be you can have one variable. Set it to 25 in your viewWillAppear say rowCount = 25. Then on each call to URL change that variable to

> `rowCount = rowCount + 25;`

This is how you can achieve it.

Comment: i am returning [myarray count] in `numberOfRowsInSection` method and myarray contains 2000 rows.. how to return 25 rows here..

Comment: after writing this logic, it will work nicely for very first time because it wil fetch only 25 rows for first time but for second time it wil fetch 50 rows.. i do not want to fetch my first 25 data.. i want to fetch next 25 data.

Comment: @Krunal where are you saving this data?? In Array?

Comment: i am fetching data from url and storing it in an dictionary and copying dictionary to array and passing this array to tableview

Comment: Ok. So you have 2000 dictionary. So next time when you load next 25. Clear you previous array and add new 25 rows.

Comment: There are 2000 rows in url, i want to fetch only 25 rows, after writing your logic my tableview displays only 25 rows but unnecessarily it fetches all data.. how to avoid all fetching of data from url ?

Comment: @Krunal this is only possible by making changes on URL side. There's no straight forward way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suggest to change your Web Service logic with paging functionality...where your 1st hit returns 25 records and 2nd hit returns records from 26 to 50 records...... and in iPhone app you will hit your web service in last cell 24th cell (like load more functionality) you can add records in your array in web service response.... :)

Cheers....happy coding..